# GLSL: How to update the position of each vertex with random values in vertex-shader?

Tags: three.js, glsl, blender, vertex-shader

I am new to vertex-shader and I am using threejs morphTargets and Points material to render my object's mesh and I am using vertex-shader for rendering and animating the mesh.

At every vertex I have placed a sphere image(say molecules) and I want them to vibrate randomly in x and y directions. I am trying to add some random values so that they vibrate at same rate in random directions.

```
void main() {

    //Morph the position based on morphTargets
    vec3 morphed = vec3( 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 );
    morphed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[0];
    morphed += position;

    // // vibrate the molecules based on temperature
     float degrees = temperature + 60.0;
     float amplitude = degrees + 100.0 / degrees;
     float rand1 = (random * rand(position.xy)  * amplitude) * 0.00001;
     morphed.x = morphed.x + rand1;
     morphed.y = morphed.y + rand1;
    //morphed.z = morphed.z + rand1;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( morphed, 1.0 );
}
```

The above code is vibrating the molecules in same direction, it looks like entire molecule container is moving not the molecules.

So how can I get the random vibrations for each vertex?

Comment: As far as I know there's no `random` function in WebGL - you would need to pass in a randomised number for each of your spheres that gets updated every time.

Comment: Or you can write your own `rand()` function. [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXsWftRdsvU).

Comment: Another note is that even if you get a random function, you will need to update each point and save the output so that the positions are continuous (lets say your position goes from 0,0 to (-1, 0 ) to (37, 0) etc. A cheaper solution may be to use a noise function for the random offset.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [noise function](https://github.com/stegu/webgl-noise), which should guarantee that the motion is continuous.